# Getting SSL certificate to work with Payara 4.1

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, glassfish, payara

I'm having a major pain getting my new SSL certificate to work with GlassFish 3.1.2.2. My current SSL certificate is due to expire soon, so I ordered a renewal at GlobalSign.

With my current SSL certificate I get following response (this is done through SoapUI for testing purposes):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Server: Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2
Pragma: No-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 13:38:32 GMT

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>..(xmlresponse)..</xml>
```

However, with the new SSL certificate active, I get following message:

SoapUI:

```
Error getting response; javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake.
```

Browser:

```
This page can’t be displayed

Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to  again. If this error persists, contact your site administrator.
```

The only thing I changed in the config of glassfish is the following:

Configurations > server-config > HTTP Service > Http Listeners > http-listener-2 > SSL tab

- The Certificate NickName field from my old alias (mydomain) to my new alias (mydomain.net), which matches the alias of my private key in the keystore
- The Key Store field value (file name) from the old keystore (server.keystore) to my new keystore (ssl_mydomain_net.jks)

Both new and old keystores are inside the `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\mydomain\config` folder.

**Old SSL settings:**

[image: Old SSL]

**New SSL settings:**

[image: New SSL]

I already had contact with GlobalSign support and we verified that the keystore is correctly generated.

When I run `keytool -list -keystore ssl_mydomain_net.jks` I get following output which should be correct:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

root, Jan 8, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <...>
intermediate, Jan 8, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <...>
<mydomain>.net, Jan 8, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): <...>
```

As far as I concluded, it has something to do with Glassfish. Does anyone have any idea because I'm out of options here...

---

**Update January 13th, 2016**

I upgraded from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Payara 4.1 (which is basicly Glassfish 4.1). I created a new fresh domain and noticed that by default the following jks files were in the *mydomain/config* folder:

- cacerts.jks
- keystore.jks

I added my own jks (ssl_mydomain_net.jks) to this folder and adjusted the settings for the http-listener-2 as above in the new SSL image. This gave me the same result as mentioned at the start of this post.

What am I missing? Do I have to adjust something to the default jks files? Do I have to create a csr from the keystore.jks instead of my own made keystore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What do I need?**

- A GlobalSign SSL Certificate
- Windows server with IIS installed
- Payara instance

**Getting your certificate from GlobalSign**

Order or renew your SSL certificate at the GlobalSign website. During the process, choose the option *Order with AutoCSR*. The password of the new certificate will exist out of a password that you have to give during the creating process added by an extra string created by GlobalSign. Please remember this password as you will need it in the next phases.

Once your order is complete, you should be receive a PFX file. Copy this file to the Windows server where IIS is running.

**Setting/Changing the master password for Payara**

The password of the certificate which will contain your private and public key will have to match the master password of Payara (This can be freely chosen, this is NOT the password of your certification request at GlobalSign). You can change the master password by running following command:

```
asadmin change-master-password –savemasterpassword=true mydomain
```

**Installing the certificate**

1. Right click the PFX file and choose *Install PFX*
2. At the welcome screen, click *Next*
3. At the *File to import* screen, click *Next* as the PFX file location should be in there by default.
4. Enter the password. Remember, this is the password you gave up at the certificate creation extended by the string GlobalSign created.
5. Select the *Mark this key as exportable.* option.
6. Select the *Include all extended properties.* option.
7. Click Next
8. In the Certificate Store window, choose the *Place all certificates in the following* store option.
9. Click the *Browse* button.
10. Choose the *Personal* store.
11. Click *OK*
12. Click *Next*
13. Click *Finish*

**Export the public and private key**

14. Open the Microsoft Management Console (Start > Run > mmc > OK)
15. Click *File > Add/Remove Snap-ins*
16. Choose *Certificates* under the Available snap-ins list
17. Click the *Add* button
18. In the next window, choose the *My user account* option
19. Click *Finish*
20. Click *OK*
21. In the management console, expand *Certificates - Current User > Personal > Certificates*. If all want correct, you should see 3 certificates: GlobalSign Domain Validation CA, GlobalSign Root CA and *mydomain.net*.
22. Right click the *mydomain.net* entry
23. Choose *All Tasks > Export...*
24. In the welcome screen, press *Next*
25. Choose *Yes, export the private key* option
26. Click Next
27. In the Export File Format window, Choose *Personal Information Exchange - PKCS # 12 (.PFX)* and select the *Include all certificates in the certification path if possible* and *Export all extended properties* options.
28. Click Next
29. In the Password window, enter your Payara master password (this has to match!)
30. Click Next
31. Select the location were you want to put the export PFX file (e.g. mydomain.pfx) and click Next.
32. Click Finish

**Getting the alias name**

Run the following command to find out the generated alias name:

```
keytool -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mydomain.pfx
```

You will have to enter your keystore password, which should be the same as your Payara master password (see step 29).

When this command runs succesful, you should see your alias on the first line of the export. This looks like a long string of text (e.g. {fa2ebfd3-z11b-492d-2c73-f5z199732p2k}) followed by the date. Copy this string of text as we will need it later.

**Adding the certificate to Payara**

These are the two important steps that I was missing. We have to add the certificate to the *cacerts.jks* and *keystore.jks* who is located in the `payara_install_folder/glassfish/domains/mydomain/config`. This can be done by following two commands:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <payara masterpassword> \
-destkeypass <payara masterpassword> -destkeystore cacerts.jks \
-srckeystore mydomain.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
-srcstorepass <payara masterpassword> \
-alias mydomain_alias_name //in our example this would be {fa2ebfd3-z11b-492d-2c73-f5z199732p2k}

keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass <payara masterpassword> \
-destkeypass <payara masterpassword> -destkeystore keystore.jks \
-srckeystore mydomain.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
-srcstorepass <payara masterpassword> \
-alias mydomain_alias_name //in our example this would be {fa2ebfd3-z11b-492d-2c73-f5z199732p2k}
```

**Setting http-listener in Payara**

1. Open your Payara admin console (normally this would be http://localhost:4848)
2. Go to Configurations > server-config > HTTP Service > HTTP Listeners > http-listener-2
3. Enable Security on the General tab
4. On the SSL tab, Enable SSL3 and TLS
5. In the Certificate NickName enter mydomain_alias_name (in our case {fa2ebfd3-z11b-492d-2c73-f5z199732p2k})
6. In the Key Store field, enter keystore.jks
7. Press the Save button
8. Restart your domain
9. Test if it works! :)

Thanks a lot to GlobalSign support and Max Lam who created a guide [How To Install Comodo SSL Certificate Chain On Payara / Glassfish 4.x](http://www.developerscrappad.com/2124/java/java-ee/how-to-install-comodo-ssl-certificate-chain-on-payara-glassfish-4-x/). Combining all this knowledge made me come up with the solution.

There is probably a way to replace the *Installing the certificate* and *Export the public and private key* part by running keytool commands. But as I'm not a 100% familiar with certificates, I left those out. If someone can tell me the right commands, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add your new certificate to the truststore of the JVM that your server is using. If you take a look to your output when list the certificates of your keystore, you could see that your new certificate is not a trustedCertEntry.